# «antaŭ tio, ke» anstataŭ «antaŭ ol»

Tags: word-usage, prepositions, word-difference, subordinate-clauses

Is it grammatically valid to say «antaŭ tio, ke» in place of «antaŭ ol»? For example, instead of this.

> La monado ŝtelis mian kukon antaŭ ol mi povis rimarki [tion].

Could one say this instead, where «tio» represents the subclause?

> La monado ŝtelis mian kukon antaŭ tio, ke mi povis rimarki [tion].

I am aware that «antaŭ tio, ke» has like no hits in the Tekstaro (I think), so I am only asking about grammatical correctness as opposed to good speaking habits. Was just curious about whether such a construction makes sense, and, if it does, whether it would have the same meaning as «antaŭ ol».

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to PMEG it could be perfectly logic to say ***antaŭ tio ke*** in place of ***antaŭ ol***, although the second is vastly used and for that reason preferable to the other, in order to avoid misunderstandings.

> [PMEG: 33.7. Aliaj subfrazoj – *apenaŭ, dum, ĝis, kvankam, kvazaŭ,
>   ol*](https://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/subfrazoj/aliaj.html#i-jjr)
>
> Logikaj estus ankaŭ *antaŭ ke* (= *antaŭ tio ke*), kaj *post ke* (=
>   *post tio ke*), sed tiuj esprimoj ne estas praktike uzataj. Estas rekomendinde uzi *antaŭ ol* kaj *post kiam*, ĉar ili estas plej facile
>   komprenataj ĝuste pro sia kutimeco.

Comment: I kind of like "antaŭ ke" and "post ke" because they seem more "regular" than "antaŭ ol" and "post kiam", because they both use "ke" instead of differing. I wonder why "antaŭ ol" and "post kiam" are more common.